# Defining a CanCan ability that goes through a belongs_to and a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I've been bothering with this issue for awhile. I have group membership modeled like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :is_owner
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :locations
end
```

Groups also have many locations, which looks like:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I'm trying to create an ability that will allow users to only view locations that belong to their Groups (Group ownership is done through the is_owner field on Membership). Here is what I've been trying:

`can :read, Location, :group => { :memberships => { :user_id => user.id, :is_owner => true } }`

This gives me the following error:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: group.memberships`

Is there a way to create this ability? I have tried a ton of variations on this ability, and none work. I can't use a block because I want it to work an index action. As a work-around, I'm looping through all locations and using `select!` to pick out the ones that I `can :read`... obviously this is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AR:Relation directly. I didn't mention HOW cancan accepts SQL joins.

```
can :read, Location, Location.includes(:group => {:memberships = {}}).where(:group => { :memberships => { :user_id => user.id, :is_owner => true } })
```

Or:

```
can :read, Location, Location.includes(:group => {:memberships = {}}).where(["memberships.user_id = ? AND memberships.is_owner is ?", user.id, true]) do |location|
  location.group.memberships.exists?(:user_id => user.id, :is_owner => true)
end
```

Comment: This throws `Unable to merge an Active Record scope with other conditions. Instead use a hash or SQL`, even when there are no other abilities defined for `:read Location`

Comment: Show all your ability definitions for Location. Somewhere ability for :read, :index, :show or any other aliased to :read method is set as hash.

Comment: No. That's the only ability for Location. I think what I want to do is impossible without monkey patching: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/646

Comment: Ok, i've just look at `https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb'. You can try pass conditions as array. Updated.